# What's the difference between "require" and "if" statement in a solidity smart contract

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

Require is an error handling global function in solidity which is basically operates in the manner that if the condition within require comes out to be true then the compiler will execute the piece of code written beneath it.
However the general logical statement if also serves the same purpose within solidity,
so wanted to know if there is a difference b/w both of these.

Answer (score 5):

The difference is that `require()` is an error handling statement like you had stated, but if this statement fails, the transaction is reverted.  Whereas if you had an `if else` statement, you would have to make sure to revert the transaction yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It is preferable to use If because it is gas efficient.

Answer (score 0):

**require**

Reverts on failure,use for error handling.
Calling require(x) when x=false

````
  ```if (amount > msg.value / 2 ether)
        revert("Not enough Ether provided.");```
````

Alternative way to do it:

````
    ```require(
        amount <= msg.value / 2 ether,
        "Not enough Ether provided."
    );```
````

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.23/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions

**if statement**

if false then continues execution.
Does not revert.

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.23/grammar.html#a4.SolidityParser.ifStatement